# how to turn off notification programmatically in android when app running?

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I am trying to develop an **android** app in which i am implementing chat functionality.
*but when i receive the message it makes a notification sound.*
How can i stop the notification when the user is using the app **programmatically**?

```
 private void ChatNotifications(String uid, String fuid, String message) {
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            notiStyle.setBigContentTitle("message");
            // notiStyle.setSummaryText(quote);
            notiStyle.bigText(message);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Loading.class);

            resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(Loading.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            //Uri defaultSoundUri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.therevew.quotes/" + R.raw.hello);
            Uri defaultSoundUri1= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                    //  .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ii_launcher))
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri1)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notificationColor))
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle("message")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(101/* ID of notification */, notiStyle.build());
        }
```

Comment: Please do some research over internet or prev questions on SO before posting questions.

Answer (score 3):

First part is

> "message it makes a notification sound."

First check if application is in foreground or not if it is then, To stop sound use `set defaults to 0 and sound to null`. change the method params like this `.setSound(isInForeGround ? null : uri).`

> How can i stop the notification when the user is using the app
> programmatically?

I guess this what you should follow;

> As per user experience is concerned you should not stop notifications,
> you just have to consume them in a way user should not able to see
> them pilled up when app is open in notificationBar.
>
> As Chatting application is concerned you should've used something as
> channel to send receive messages if two users are online and chatting
> so when you receive message.
>
> So just don't create pending intent from
> the data you receive for particular chat in noticiationBar.

Hope this clears your concept consuming notification. Hope this helps.

Comment: how i am change default values?

Comment: @deepak-mittal Just check if your application is in foreground then use Conditional operator in this method .setSound( isinForeground ? null : uri). This will solve your problem. For application in foreground I urge you to do some internet research to get the best approach... hope this helps

Comment: @DEEPAKMITTAL please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
 //if you use fcm then try       

   @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            if (isForeground(getApplicationContext())) {
              //if in forground then your operation
            // if app is running them
            } else {
             //if in background then perform notification operation
                sendNotification(message);
            }
        }
    }


        private static boolean isForeground(Context context) {
                    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
                    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
                    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : tasks) {
                        if (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND == appProcess.importance && packageName.equals(appProcess.processName)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove

```
.setSound(defaultSoundUri1)
```

from

```
 Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                    //  .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ii_launcher))
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri1)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notificationColor))
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle("message")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
```

when you do not need any sound. 
If this will not help you, try to to do this:

```
Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                    //  .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ii_launcher))
                    .setSound(null)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notificationColor))
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle("message")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setStyle(notiStyle).build();
myNotification.defaults = 0;
```

Comment: if i am removing this **.setSound(defaultSoundUri1)** . notification stop work 
permanently.

Answer (score -1):

First set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

in AndroidManifest
then do this where required

```
  final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Comment: Will this not affect all apps and not just the calling app?