# Android Hide & Disable Notification (Status) Bar in oreo

Tags: android

The method for kiosking an application by disabling pull and click of the status bar does not work on android 8. As anserwed on [How to disable status bar click and pull down in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969086/how-to-disable-status-bar-click-and-pull-down-in-android).

I have tested it on android 7 and less and it works, but the status bar still pulls down when pulled on android 8.

I didnt find any solution for the same.
Please let me know if there is any solution that works for oreo also.

Thanks!

Comment: In Above link, User 2nd Option for Android Oreo and above. User can Pull down but it will immediately pull up. I am using 2nd option for the My Kiosk AApp.

Comment: its working, but is not restricted everytime. means i want to disable that.. that window tray will not open in any condition.

Comment: That is not possible In android Oreo and Above.

Comment: okay.. thanks. it is managable upto now.. can you tell me how can i implement this in all activities?

Comment: should i define this in all activities separately?

Comment: No. You can add in in only main activity.

Comment: If i am adding this only in 1 activity, then in only that activity, the bar stopped. but i want that in my whole application. SO how would i able to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using below code in `MainActivity`.

```
//Global Declaration
Handler collapseNotificationHandler;

@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.d(tag, "window focus changed");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        collapseNow();
    }
}
```

Collapse Method

```
public void collapseNow() {

    try {
        // Initialize 'collapseNotificationHandler'
        if (collapseNotificationHandler == null) {
            collapseNotificationHandler = new Handler();
        }

        // Post a Runnable with some delay - currently set to 300 ms
        collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'
                Object statusBarService = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

                try {
                    statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Method collapseStatusBar = null;
                try {
                    // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
                    // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
                    } else {
                        collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

                try {
                    collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Currently, the delay is 10 ms. You can change this
                // value to suit your needs.
                collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(this, 10L);
            }
        }, 10L);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also using this code.But my question is how can i achieve this in all activities. Do i have to implement the whole code in all the activities or can i do this in a single class and implement this?

Comment: i set only in main activity , it is working when i am in the main activity, but when i jump to any other activity then, it is not working

Comment: I will frame you the whole thing, i am making a gate application in which if I lock my app then it will be restricted to my app in the phone and if it is unlocked by password, then i have to disable all locks and enable notification bar. If i again lock the app, then i have to disable the bar.. This is the whole scenario

Comment: I solved it.. thanks for your help. I use a boolean and make it true in main activity when the app is running and when it got destroyed i change it to false and solved my problem.

Comment: 1 thing i want to ask, this task is running in the background that making my app slow.. is there any solution for that?